# How to map through Object inside Array inside Object inside Array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

I have the following Array and want to access a nested element. How do I do that?

```js
var productionSteps = [
  0: {
    displayName: "..."
    final: ...
    generateQRCode: ...
    inputs: [
      0: {
        "asset":"ValueAsset", "amount":1000
      },
      1: {...},
      2: {...},
      3: {...},
    ]
    
  },
  1: {...},
  2: {...},
  3: {...}
]
```

I want to map through the "asset" inside of the input for every element of the parent Array. Therefore I want my console.log to return "ValueAsset", ... and so on.

I have tried this the following way but only reach a specific Input Array, but I want to map through all of them.

```js
{Object.values(productionSteps).map((value: any, index) => {
        return (
          console.log(JSON.stringify(value.inputs[0]
          ))
        );
      })}
```

How would I map through the input Array to console log all of the "asset"?

Comment: This is not a valid html object

Answer (score 1):

I solved this the following way:

```js
{Object.values(productionSteps).map((value: any, index) => {
        return (
          value.inputs.map((value: any) => {
            return (
              console.log(JSON.stringify(value.assetGroup))
            )
          }
          ))
      }
      )
      }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).